# Max value of Stopwatch

Tags: c#

I've been using Stopwatch as a general benchmarking tool for program execution, but I'm worried about potential rollover.

I am measuring a specific area of my program, which may perform hundreds of thousands of repetitive operations (or more), which can span days. It is essentially full program execution.

I've thought about migrating to an implementation using DateTime.UtcNow, but if Stopwatch has the capability, I would largely prefer Stopwatch.

Edit:

The comment below answered my question. It would take thousands of years for Stopwatch to overflow.

Comment: You're unlikely to overflow a `long`, the max value of which is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.

Comment: I wish I could mark this as my answer.